# Laravel redirect after anything

Tags: php, laravel

using laravel 5.6 right now, will update to 5.8 soon.

The question is simple, I want to redirect after login (for this time, just want to add some redirect logic in order to use it may be later).
In this case, I set up the login middleware to send the `$request->getBackURI()` as a param to the login view.

Once I am on the login form I can see the redirect_to as a querystring, but when I do the login and I want to see the `$request->get('redirect_to')` it's empty, of course, because I didn't send it as a param to the actually login controller.

I saved it in the session of the request but suddenly an other variable I didn't see appeared

```
{session:
...
url => www.foo.bar/pathtoredirect,
redirect_to => /pathtoredirect} -> this is the one I stored
```

the thing is, once I get to the redirect method I really cant access to anything, it'a a void function

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    return route('main.index');
}
```

if I include the Request object I get

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::redirectTo(), 0 passed ... on line 15 and exactly 1 expected
```

I know, for this case that is just one redirect, from path -> login -> path I can use

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    return back();
}
```

I just want to know if there is any way I can implement my way of doing the things or will the Laravel way works every single time I want (Ex: more than just 1 redirect, imagine some middlewares requests or facebook login)

Comment: Are you using laravel built in login?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can overwrite default login function and after login function also in Laravel

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
    * The user has been authenticated.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  mixed  $user
    * @return mixed
    */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
      // in here you can do what ever you want 
        $path = $request->get('redirect_to')
        return redirect($path);
    }
}
```

and globally you can call request without passing

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
   $path = request()->redirect_to;
   or 
   $path = \Request::get('redirect_to');
    return back();
}
```

Comment: I should improve my POO concepts for real. Can you explain my why the authenticated function is empty in the `trait AuthenticatesUsers` ?? Is getting called  by `sendLoginResponse`, or no? ( I cant post code here)

Comment: earlier version of laravel there is no function like this. we can redirect only that path. but new versions after authorization we can save session or we can do whatever we need. its empty we can directly use that function but when you update composer your file will be change. so better you overwrite this function.

Comment: by the way you using default login process ? yes please post and let me know what is exactly you need ?

Comment: yes, im using default and Socialite for facebook login. And I need to redirect to some path once is logged in. by a query param or anything else.